# Design Pattern for Custom Fields in Relational Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, oracle, database-design

I have assigned a task to create (relatively) simple reporting system. In these system, user will be shown a table result of report. A table has some fields and each field give some part of information to user in each record. My problem however is that each report field will not be declared by **developer**. It must be declared by **user** of system. So my reports table are dynamic.

I saw example in '[Data Driven Custom View Engine in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/946/data-driven-custom-view-engine-aspnet-mvc)' for creating dynamic forms using Asp.net MVC Framework but I don't know that is appropriate for my system or not.

**Update1:**

Currently I ended with following Entity Relationship Diagram:

[image]

In above diagram, I store every record for report in `Report` table. Also I store type of report in `ReportType`. For each field that will be used in report record I will use a `ReportFieldValue`. Type of fields will be stored in `ReportField`.

So If I want to add a record to my db first I add a row to `Report` Table. Then for each added record fields I will add a row to `ReportFieldValue` table.

However as you may notice, in these approach I must store every field value in char(255). The problem is for fields type like `datetime` that should not be stored as string. Is there any design pattern or architecture for this type of systems?

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? is it mysql, oracle or sql server?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I didn't select any database, but you answer in whatever you like.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Avoid stringly-typed data by replacing `VALUE` with `NUMBER_VALUE`, `DATE_VALUE`, `STRING_VALUE`.  Those three types are good enough most of the time. You can add XMLTYPE and other fancy columns later if they're needed.  And for Oracle, use VARCHAR2 instead of CHAR to conserve space.

Always try to store values as the correct type.  Native data types are faster (both because type conversion is unnecessary and because the optimizer can better reason about the values better and generate smarter execution plans), smaller, easier to use, and safer.

Oracle has a generic data type system (ANYTYPE, ANYDATA, and ANYDATASET), but those types are difficult to use and should be avoided in most cases.

Architects often think using a single field for all data makes things easier.  It makes it easier to generate pretty pictures of the data model but it makes everything
else more difficult.  Consider these issues:

1. You cannot do anything interesting with data without knowing the type.  Even to display data it's useful to know the type to justify the text.  In 99.9% of all
   use cases it will be obvious to the user which of the 3 columns is relevant.
2. Developing type-safe queries against stringly-typed data is painful.  For example, let's say you want to find "Date of Birth" for people born in this millennium:

   ```
    select *
    from ReportFieldValue
    join ReportField
        on ReportFieldValue.ReportFieldid = ReportField.id
    where ReportField.name = 'Date of Birth'
        and to_date(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD') > date '2000-01-01'
   ```

Can you spot the bug?  The above query is dangerous, even if you stored the date in the correct format, and very few developers know how to properly fix it.  Oracle has optimizations that make it difficult to force a specific order of operations.  You'll need a query like this to be safe:

```
    select *
    from
    (
        select ReportFieldValue.*, ReportField.*
            --ROWNUM ensures type safe by preventing view merging and predicate pushing.
            ,rownum
        from ReportFieldValue
        join ReportField
            on ReportFieldValue.ReportFieldid = ReportField.id
        where ReportField.name = 'Date of Birth'
    )
    where to_date(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD') > date '2000-01-01';
You don't want to have to tell every developer to write their queries that way.
```

Comment: +1 for "stringly-typed", and the value of using separate columns for each type. I've performed a conversion from the former to the latter, and the benefits are huge.

Comment: @Jon Heller kindly explain the difference between two queries above. They both seems same to me logically.

Comment: @Rahul You're right, they look logically equivalent.  The difference is that the `ROWNUM` forces the inline view to be executed first.  This ensures the name filter is applied before the value filter, which forces the date conversion to only happen for the correct types.  It's confusing and hard to reproduce, since Oracle may automatically apply the name filter before the value filter in some cases, which is why it's best to avoid these situations with a table change.

Comment: @JonHeller Understood. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 8):

Your design is a variation of the Entity Attribute Value (EAV) data model, which is often regarded as an anti-pattern in database design.

Maybe a better approach for you would be to create a reporting values table with, say, 300 columns (NUMBER_VALUE_1 through NUMBER_VALUE_100, VARCHAR2_VALUE_1..100, and DATE_VALUE_1..100).

Then, design the rest of your data model around tracking which reports use which columns and what they use each column for.

This has two benefits: first, you are not storing dates and numbers in strings (the benefits of which have already been pointed out), and second, you avoid many of the performance and data integrity issues associated with the EAV model.

### EDIT -- adding some empirical results of an EAV model

Using an Oracle 11g2 database, I moved 30,000 records from one table into an EAV data model.  I then queried the model to get those 30,000 records back.

```
SELECT SUM (header_id * LENGTH (ordered_item) * (SYSDATE - schedule_ship_date))
FROM   (SELECT rf.report_type_id,
               rv.report_header_id,
               rv.report_record_id,
               MAX (DECODE (rf.report_field_name, 'HEADER_ID', rv.number_value, NULL)) header_id,
               MAX (DECODE (rf.report_field_name, 'LINE_ID', rv.number_value, NULL)) line_id,
               MAX (DECODE (rf.report_field_name, 'ORDERED_ITEM', rv.char_value, NULL)) ordered_item,
               MAX (DECODE (rf.report_field_name, 'SCHEDULE_SHIP_DATE', rv.date_value, NULL)) schedule_ship_date
        FROM   eav_report_record_values rv INNER JOIN eav_report_fields rf ON rf.report_field_id = rv.report_field_id
        WHERE  rv.report_header_id = 20 
        GROUP BY rf.report_type_id, rv.report_header_id, rv.report_record_id)
```

The results were:

```
1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:22.62

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                             |     1 |  2026 |    53  (67)|
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                 |                             |     1 |  2026 |            |
|   2 |   VIEW                          |                             |   130K|   251M|    53  (67)|
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                |                             |   130K|   261M|    53  (67)|
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                |                             |       |       |            |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS               |                             |   130K|   261M|    36  (50)|
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL         | EAV_REPORT_FIELDS           |   350 | 15050 |    18   (0)|
|*  7 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN          | EAV_REPORT_RECORD_VALUES_N1 |   130K|       |     0   (0)|
|*  8 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EAV_REPORT_RECORD_VALUES    |   372 |   749K|     0   (0)|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   7 - access("RV"."REPORT_HEADER_ID"=20)
   8 - filter("RF"."REPORT_FIELD_ID"="RV"."REPORT_FIELD_ID")

Note
-----
   - 'PLAN_TABLE' is old version


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          4  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
     275480  consistent gets
        465  physical reads
          0  redo size
        307  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        252  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

That's 22 seconds to get 30,000 rows of 4 columns each.  That is *way* too long.  From a flat table we'd be looking at under 2 seconds, easy.

Comment: The EAV model is useful in the appropriate scenario, and the questioner's sounds like one of them.  Creating 300 columns sounds like it would become a nightmare to work with, especially if a need to use, link or import/export to the data to/from other systems arises!

Comment: I have to disagree.  If a report really needed all 300 columns, I'd be grateful to have them all in one record.  I cannot speak to all RDBMS platforms, but on Oracle, a single record will perform orders of magnitude better than an EAV model.  Also, depending on how much time you have, you can make the single-record approach very easy to work with (e.g., put logic in your application that uses the metadata to compile a report-specific database view whenever the metadata changes)

Comment: I don't know which is _worse_, EAV or 300 anonymous columns.

Comment: Having worked with both, I definitely think the former is worse.  You can mitigate the difficulties of the 300-column approach with effort (e.g., a dynamically-maintained view layer based on metadata).  There is little you can do to mitigate the drawbacks of EAV, unless you've got very (unrealistically?) simple requirements (e.g., no filter conditions on your reports and/or not a lot of report data in the system).

Comment: How would you index so many fields, db would be 300 times bigger then actual data because of many indexes and you would store millions of nulls. Also you would have to build dynamic sql to perform search on such set. I've seen such model in action (Meridio DMS) and it can be outperformed easily with normalised data approach easily. 30k recoords in 2 sec is still waaaay to long.

Comment: A "normalized data approach" was excluded as a solution by the OP, assuming, by normalized you mean something close to 3rd normal form.  He specifically wants a "data driven" model.

Comment: It's true, a 300 column table will store a lot of byte lengths (in Oracle), making the average row take between 1 and 2 KB.  You can mitigate that a lot by interleaving the char, number, and date columns and using the lowest numbers first.  If you **really** are worried about it, you can vertically partition the table.  Again, my point is that EAV has fundamental problems that are very difficult to work around.  A big flat table, while problematic, can at least be managed.  (Also, a quick test shows that 30,000 records accessed by index takes under 1 second).

Comment: There is a limit of 64 secondary indexes in InnoDB.

Answer (score 5):

Use MariaDB, with it's [Dynamic Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/dynamic-columns/).  Effectively, that lets you put all the miscellany columns into a single column, yet still give you efficient access to them.

I would keep a few of the common fields in their own columns.

[More discussion of EAV](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav) and suggestions (and how to do it without Dynamic Columns).

Comment: And now MySQL has a JSON column datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a very good point about storing data in the correct data types.
And i agree that this does pose a problem for user-defined data systems.

One way of solveing this problem is by adding tables for each data type group (ints, floating points, strings, binary and dates, instead of keeping the value in the `ReportFieldValue` table. 
However, this will make your life harder since you will have to select and join multiple tables in order to get a single result.

another way would be to add a data type column in the `ReportFieldValue` and create a user defined function to dynamically cast the data from strings to the appropriate data type (using the value in the data type column), so that you can use that for sorting, searching etc`.

Sql server also has a data type called [`sql_variant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) that should support multiple types, and though I've never worked with it it's documentation seems promising.