# How to create dynamic parser?

Tags: parsing, design-patterns, architecture

I want to create something called `dynamic parser`.

My project input is some data file like `XML`, `Excel`, `CSV`and ... file and I must parse it and extract its records and its fields and finally save it to SQL Server database.

My problem is that fields of the record is dynamic and I can not write parser in development time. I must provide parser in run-time. By dynamic I mean a user select each record fields using a Web UI. So, I know the numbers of fields in each record in run-time and some information about each field like its name and so on.

I discussed this type of project in question titled ['Design Pattern for Custom Fields in Relational Database'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721343/design-pattern-for-custom-fields-in-relational-database).

I also looked at [Parser Generator](http://martinfowler.com/dslCatalog/parserGenerator.html) but i did not get enought information about it and I don't know it is really related to my problem or not.

Is there any design pattern for this type of problem?

Comment: Your question is basically similar to "what is the appropriate tool to build a house?". There is none, because you need many of them, and the right tools depend on how you choose to build the house. Start coding, and patterns will emerge.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of fields and the field names then extract the data from the file and then build a query using string concatenation