# What database schema to use for storing survey answers

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle, database-design, schema

I'm required for designing a survey system for our customer.
It's based on `asp.net`, and the database used is `oracle`.

I've no experience here so I'd like to ask for advice about:

1. What database schema to use for storing user answers, I'm afraid my current design is likely to have performance issue...

About the survey:

1. There'll be two or more surveys going on at the same time.
2. Surveys may be triggered once a year or more frequently, so I think I need a Survey Period table.
3. Surveys are targeting different products, so there'll be a mapping between products and surveys

Currently my design:

Survey Category table

```
+------------+--------------+
| CatageryId | CatageryName |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | cat1         |
|          2 | cat2         |
+------------+--------------+
```

Survey Category version table

```
+-----------+------------+--------------------+
| VersionId | CatageryId | VersionDescription |
+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|         1 |          1 | 'cat1 version1'    |
|         2 |          1 | 'cat1 version2'    |
|         3 |          2 | 'cat2 version1'    |
+-----------+------------+--------------------+
```

Survey Period Table

```
+----------+--------------------+
| PeriodId | PeriodDescription  |
+----------+--------------------+
|        1 |  'cat1 period2016' |
|        2 |  'cat1 period2017' |
|        3 |  'cat2 period2016' |
+----------+--------------------+
```

Survey Period-Version map table

```
+----------+-----------+
| PeriodId | VersionId |
+----------+-----------+
|        1 |         1 |
|        1 |         2 |
|        2 |         1 |
|        3 |         3 |
+----------+-----------+
```

A Version-Question map table

```
+--------------+------------+
| VersionId |  | QuestionId |
+--------------+------------+
|            1 |          1 |
|            1 |          2 |
|            1 |          3 |
|            2 |          1 |
|            2 |          2 |
|            3 |          1 |
+--------------+------------+
```

A Version-Product map table

```
+-----------+-----------+
| VersionId | ProductId |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 | 'prodA'   |
|         1 | 'prodB'   |
|         1 | 'prodC'   |
|         2 | 'prodA'   |
+-----------+-----------+
```

And to Store the survey result data, I have to put lots of duplicated information between rows of record:

User Answer table

`+----------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+
| AnswerId | QuestionId | PeriodId | UserId/Ip | ProductId | Answer | VersionId |
+----------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+
|        1 |          1 |        1 | 'adam'    | 'prodA'   | 'Yes'  |         2 |
|        2 |          2 |        1 | 'Joe'     | 'prodA'   | 'Yes'  |         2 |
|        3 |          1 |        2 | 'adam'    | 'prodB'   | 'A'    |         3 |
+----------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+`

We're expecting tens of products and thousands of users for this system.
So assume 30 products, 5000 users, 50 questions per survey and 4 surveys per year

in the current design, there'll be 5000 * 4 * 50 * 30 = 30 millions of records added in the User Answer Table per year, 
I'm really afraid if it could still work properly..., so any suggestions for optimizing?

**Edit 1:**
Add VersionId column in user answer table as suggested.

Comment: You don't have VersionId in your Answer table. How would you know for which survey version this answer belongs to? The volumes which you have suggested can be managed by an Oracle database. You can plan to implement partitioning in your answer table based on PeriodId.

Comment: @phonetic_man , yes you're right, I'll edit to add one more column...I'll also find more information about partition, thank you very much.

Comment: Here is a link from documentation on partitioning. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm

Comment: @phonetic_man, thanks so much for your kindly help. After reading this I think I'll do a list partitioning on the PeriodId column. Hope there'll be no issue because I think the current database design is a little too complicated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a case of premature optimization.  You should probably worry more about correctness and flexibility than performance.

30 million rows per year, especially in these skinny tables, is a small amount of data for any Oracle system.  Don't worry too much about indexes and partitioning yet, those can be added later if necessary.

Your solution is similar to the Entity Attribute Value (EAV) model.  It's worth knowing that term since much has been written about it.  There are 2 common problems with EAV models you want to avoid:

1. **Avoid extremes.**  Don't use EAV for *everything*, but don't completely avoid it either.  EAV is slow and inconvenient compared to a normal table structure.  It should not be used for every interesting columns, otherwise you have created a database within a database.  For example, if virtually every survey has fields like a username and a date created, store those as regular columns and not in a generic column.  It's OK to have a column that is only populated 99% of the time.  On the other hand, it's a bad idea to always avoid the EAV and try to hack something together with 1,000 column tables or object-relational types.
2. **Always use the correct type.**  Always, always, always store data as the correct type.  Store numbers as numbers, dates as dates, and strings as strings.  Your queries will be easier, faster, and safer, if you have at least three columns for the data: ANSWER_NUMBER, ANSWER_STRING, ANSWER_DATE.  I explain the type safety problem more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31769013/409172).  Those extra columns may look bad in the model diagram, but they are a life-saver when you're querying the data.

Comment: Accepted for `30 million rows per year, especially ...`. As a newbie here, this is what I care most..

Comment: It's sad my time is so limited that I have to finish the main architecture of the program last week. I still use my original table design, but I'll learn more about the EAV model. BTW, I consider the survey result table resembles a EAV table isn't it... the xxxIDs field like attributes... And thank you for your suggestions on `use correct types`, i didn't think of it before to use different types for store a variable value.